# Auto-loading Classes. auto loading function doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm new to php & developing **php5.4** application.there i used auto loading classes.I get a fatal error so I assume it doesn't work function _autoload properly.. Please find below the code I used. When I tried it gave me the following error: please help me.

```
Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\MVCApp\index.php on line 35
```

**C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\MVCApp\index.php file**

```
<?php

        //define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath('../'));//C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs
         define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath('../'));//C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\MVCApp

        echo APPLICATION_PATH;

        $paths=array(
            APPLICATION_PATH,
            APPLICATION_PATH.'/com',
            get_include_path(),


        );
        set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));

       // echo get_include_path();//C:\Program Files\xampp\php\PEAR

        function _autoload($className)
       {
          require_once $className.'.php';
          return;
       }


          $user=new User();

          echo $user->getName();


        ?>


        C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\MVCApp\com\User.php file

        <?php
```

**C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\MVCApp\com\User.php file**

```
<?php

class User {

    public function getName()
    {
       return 'Hello Sam';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function __autoload($className)
           {
                echo $className;


           }
```

autoload function works with two underscores.not one.Now i think it should be work.